# How to install and cross-compile SDL lib to embedded linux (hisiv300)

Tags: sdl, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I'm using a board an embedded linux system with a Hi3516 chip. How Do I compile a graphic library like SDL to work on the embedded system?

Answer (score 0):

I found a guide in Chinese to install SDL for arm-hisiv300 that I followed and it works for me.

**Step 1:** Download and unzip the following files each to a separate directory:

1. freetype-2.4.10.tar.gz
2. SDL-1.2.15.tar.gz
3. SDL_ttf-2.0.11.tar.gz

**Step 2:** PATH.

I found it easier to install when I'm in root mode (`sudo su`), the problem is that you loss your PATH parameters so type the following command: `export PATH=/opt/hisi-linux/x86-arm/arm-hisiv300-linux/target/bin:$PATH`

**Step 3:** FreeType.

Go to your freetype directory and execute the following commands.

1. `./configure CC=arm-hisiv300-linux-gcc --host=arm-hisiv300-linux`.
2. `make`.
3. `make install`.

**Step 4:** SDL.

Go to your SDL directory and execute the following commands.

1. `./configure CC=arm-hisiv300-linux-gcc --host=arm-hisiv300-linux --disable-alsa --disable-pulseaudio --enable-esd=no`. (pulseaudio caused to errors in my compilation so I don't use it).
2. `make`.
3. `make install`.

**Step 5:** SDL_ttf.

Go to your SDL_ttfdirectory and execute the following commands.

1. `./configure CC=arm-hisiv300-linux-gcc --host=arm-hisiv300-linux`.
2. `make`.
3. `make install`.

**Step 6:** Copy SDL library files.

1. `mkdir -C /opt/sdl_lib`.
2. `cd /opt/sdl_lib`.
3. `cp /usr/local/include/ ./ -rf`.
4. `cp /usr/local/lib ./ -rf`.

Now you are ready to use the SDL libraries.
To compile your code, use the following command or implement it to a Makefile:

```
arm-hisiv300-linux-gcc YOURFILE.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -I/opt/sdl_lib/include -I/opt/sdl_lib/include/SDL -L/opt/sdl_lib/lib -lSDL -lSDL_ttf -Wl,-rpath -o YOURFILE
```

Hope this helps. If anyone has SDL examples in C and can add them to this answer it would be great and if you know how to compile more graphics libraries please share that info.